# how to remove the x button in the modal window using DialogDescriptor

Tags: java, swing

how to remove the x button in the modal window using DialogDescriptor?

```
DialogDescriptor.CANCEL_OPTION
```

The code:

```
  final DialogDescriptor dialogDescriptor = new DialogDescriptor(credenciaisPanel, "Selecionar Área",  true, null,
                OK_OPTION, DialogDescriptor.DEFAULT_ALIGN, null, null);
 dialogDescriptor.setClosingOptions(null);
        dialogDescriptor.setModal(true);
        dialogDescriptor.setLeaf(true);
```

I can change the button's behavior x, but I would like to remove it from view

credenciaisPanel = javax.swing.JPanel

Comment: Looking at the documentation, doesn't seem to have an option for hiding the X (unlike Jdialog with `setUndecorated(true)`)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any property in DialogDescriptor to remove the x button. Because changing the type of model JPanel to JFrame or JDialog displays error at runtime.